# Replace all words that begin and end in a certain character in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm working on a corpus of email messages, and trying to replace all html tags in the corpus with the string ''. How can I replace all html tag using the fact that they begin with >< and end with > ?

Example:

```
<html>
  <body>
  This is some random text.
 <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Should be translated to:

```
<html>
  <html>
  This is some random text.
    <html>This is some text in a paragraph.<html>
  <html>
<html>
```

Thanks

Comment: If these emails are html then you are much better off using the `XML` package. What would you want to do with, e.g., `<a href=webpage.html>Link</a>`? Return just `Link`?

Comment: I actually want to identify that there were html tag in the document, I just want to generalize them to one single <html> tag. in your example I would like it to be <html>Link<html>

Comment: Please provide an example of (at least) one of these emails.

Comment: @Yoav when adding new information, please edit your original question rather than responding in comments. That way the information can be properly formatted and you can make it clear what you want.

Comment: @Yoav What would be the result of precessing this email?

Comment: @jlhoward Please refer to the original question, I just edited it and gave an example of the output. Thanks!

Comment: Sure hope none of your emails have any  loveicons, `<3` , or even worse,  winking eyes,  ` >.<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the power of the regex with `gsub`. If you simply want to replace any `<markup_name>` by `<hml>` then `gsub("<[^>]+>", "<html>", email_text)` will do it.

The trick is `[^>]\+` which extends (`+`) the regex until the first `>` (`[^>]` matches any character that is not `>`).

Comment: When I try this I get an error that `\+` is an unrecognized escape character. If I remove the back-slash it works, e.g. `gsub("<[^>]+>", "<html>", email_text)`

Comment: Sorry, I mixed with `\\w` and sed that needs \. Thanks for the correction, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method offered only for completeness since it is less general than @Math's solution that I consider superior. Thinking that one might also use the range-quantifier pattern operators `{n,m}`. It probably has many deficiencies. It also raises the memory of a famous SO answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

```
 dat <- "<html>
   <body>
   This is some random text.
  <p>This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
 </body>
 </html>"

 gsub("<.{1,5}>", "<html>", dat)
#[1] "<html>\n  <html>\n  This is some random text.\n <html>This is some text in a paragraph.<html>\n<html>\n<html>"

> cat( gsub("<.{1,5}>", "<html>", dat) )
<html>
  <html>
  This is some random text.
 <html>This is some text in a paragraph.<html>
<html>
<html>
```